# Isolating cause of Erlang and RabbitMQ crashes

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq

We have been trying to make use of the RabbitMQ Service Bus (v3.3.4) but the central bus keeps crashing. At the moment we are not using any clustering and its hosted on Windows Server 2008 R2. We'd like to isolate the root cause but the below error is the only one we can find. Can anyone shed some light on what; if anything; we can do to find the root cause of this?

Note: There are roughly 20 consumers with roughly the same number of Topic subscriptions. Also, all the clients are .NET 4.5 using the 3.3.4 Rabbit client libraries.

```
Version=1
EventType=APPCRASH
EventTime=130658038736577295
ReportType=2
Consent=1
ReportIdentifier=7f93ccd8-9cbe-11e4-ae00-000c29c08139
IntegratorReportIdentifier=7f93ccd7-9cbe-11e4-ae00-000c29c08139
Response.type=4
Sig[0].Name=Application Name
Sig[0].Value=erl.exe
Sig[1].Name=Application Version
Sig[1].Value=0.0.0.0
Sig[2].Name=Application Timestamp
Sig[2].Value=5343035d
Sig[3].Name=Fault Module Name
Sig[3].Value=MSVCR100.dll
Sig[4].Name=Fault Module Version
Sig[4].Value=10.0.30319.1
Sig[5].Name=Fault Module Timestamp
Sig[5].Value=4ba220dc
Sig[6].Name=Exception Code
Sig[6].Value=40000015
Sig[7].Name=Exception Offset
Sig[7].Value=00000000000760d9
DynamicSig[1].Name=OS Version
DynamicSig[1].Value=6.1.7600.2.0.0.272.7
DynamicSig[2].Name=Locale ID
DynamicSig[2].Value=1033
DynamicSig[22].Name=Additional Information 1
DynamicSig[22].Value=8d79
DynamicSig[23].Name=Additional Information 2
DynamicSig[23].Value=8d79a00078e92d9c3d5d79d4324254fe
DynamicSig[24].Name=Additional Information 3
DynamicSig[24].Value=9af5
DynamicSig[25].Name=Additional Information 4
DynamicSig[25].Value=9af5b20633c279dbf44b04a614c6a1f6
UI[2]=C:\Program Files\erl6.0\erts-6.0\bin\erl.exe
UI[5]=Check online for a solution (recommended)
UI[6]=Check for a solution later (recommended)
UI[7]=Close
UI[8]=erl.exe stopped working and was closed
UI[9]=A problem caused the application to stop working correctly. Windows will notify you if a solution is available.
UI[10]=&Close
LoadedModule[0]=C:\Program Files\erl6.0\erts-6.0\bin\erl.exe
LoadedModule[1]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
LoadedModule[2]=C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
LoadedModule[3]=C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
LoadedModule[4]=C:\Windows\system32\MSVCR100.dll
LoadedModule[5]=C:\Program Files\erl6.0\erts-6.0\bin\erlexec.dll
LoadedModule[6]=C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
LoadedModule[7]=C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
LoadedModule[8]=C:\Windows\system32\LPK.dll
LoadedModule[9]=C:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll
LoadedModule[10]=C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
LoadedModule[11]=C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
LoadedModule[12]=C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
LoadedModule[13]=C:\Windows\system32\apphelp.dll
LoadedModule[14]=C:\Program Files\erl6.0\erts-6.0\bin\beam.dll
LoadedModule[15]=C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
LoadedModule[16]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
LoadedModule[17]=C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
LoadedModule[18]=C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7600.16661_none_fa62ad231704eab7\COMCTL32.dll
LoadedModule[19]=C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
LoadedModule[20]=C:\Windows\system32\COMDLG32.dll
LoadedModule[21]=C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
LoadedModule[22]=C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
LoadedModule[23]=C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll
LoadedModule[24]=C:\Windows\system32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
LoadedModule[25]=C:\Windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL
LoadedModule[26]=C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
LoadedModule[27]=C:\Windows\System32\wshtcpip.dll
LoadedModule[28]=C:\Windows\system32\NLAapi.dll
LoadedModule[29]=C:\Windows\system32\DNSAPI.dll
LoadedModule[30]=C:\Windows\System32\winrnr.dll
LoadedModule[31]=C:\Windows\system32\napinsp.dll
LoadedModule[32]=C:\Windows\System32\wship6.dll
FriendlyEventName=Stopped working
ConsentKey=APPCRASH
AppName=erl.exe
AppPath=C:\Program Files\erl6.0\erts-6.0\bin\erl.exe
```

Comment: Is there an Erlang crash dump somewhere? Also, are you keeping an eye on the memory used?

Comment: get anywhere with this, getting the same from a .net 4.6 client connecting to rabbitmq using easynetq and rabbitmq 3.5.3

Comment: See https://www.rabbitmq.com/troubleshooting.html#crash-dumps